# MQX RTCS configuration properties

Tags: mqx

Hi has anione worked with MQX ?

I do not know how to set BSP_ENET_DEVICE_COUNT in order to test the enet demo ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should look in the user_config.h and the board specific header file (e.g. TWRK60512.h for the k60 tower) for such settings. These can be found in the bsp library source.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Normally this is set on `{MQX_ROOT_DIR}\mqx\source\bsp\"your_bsp_name"\"your_bsp_name".h` 
but you can set it on user_config.h too.